# ¿Cómo actulizar registros en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysqli

Necesito actualizar su estado

**formulario.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inicio Consulta.</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>
    <?php  

    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

     $sentencia = "SELECT placa,estado,tipo_Ambulancia FROM ambulancia ORDER BY placa";
     $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);

?>

<body>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" width="200" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt" id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h3 align="center">Consulta Ambulancia</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <form method="POST" action="consultaProcesoAmbu.php">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <p align="center"><b>Placa de la ambulancia a consultar: </b></td>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <p align="center">                          
                    <label style="margin-left: 1%">Movil:</label>
                        <select name="movil">
                            <option value="TRG-542">TRG-542</option>
                            <option value="TRG-543">TRG-543</option>
                            <option value="TRG-544">TRG-544</option>
                            <option value="TRG-545">TRG-545</option>
                            <option value="MOW-930">MOW-930</option>
                            <option value="MOW-931">MOW-931</option>
                        </select>                                
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%" colspan="2">
                                        <p align="center">
                                            <input type="submit" value="consultar" name="btn-actulizar"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </form>
                                </table>
                                <input type="button" value="Volver de donde viniste!" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/Administracion.php'" />
                            </div>
                        </body>
                        </html>
```

**consulta.php**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Consultando Ambulancia...</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<?php 
echo "<body>";
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

$query = "  SELECT placa, estado, tipo_Ambulancia FROM ambulancia WHERE placa = ?";

/*Prepara la setencia SQl para su ejecucion*/
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {

    /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);

    /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /*Se transfiere los  resultados de la ultima consulta*/
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Vincula las variables a una setencia preparada para el almacenamineto de result */
    $stmt->bind_result($placa, $estado, $tipo_Ambulancia);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "

    <div align='center'>
        <table border='1' width='600' style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt' id='table1'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><h3 align='center'>Consultando Ambulancia</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>En los campos del formulario puede ver los valores actuales,
                de las ambulancias.</td>
            </tr>
            <form method='POST' action=''>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Estado :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='estado' size='20' value='".$estado."'></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
        <br><input type='button' value='Volver!' onclick='history.back(-2)' />

    </div>
    ";
    } 

}else{
    echo '<script>
                    alert("La ambulancia no existe");
         </script>';
}
?>
    </body>
    </html>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>

         <br><input type="submit" name="actualizar_Estado" value ="Actualizar Estado" onclick = "location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/modificarEstadoAmbu.php'">


         </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**actualizacion.php**

```
// Actualizamos en funcion del id que recibimos

$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


$query = "UPDATE ambulancia SET estado = 1 where id = '".$id."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query); 

if (!$result) {

    echo        '<script>
                        alert("La ambulancia NO  fue eactualizado EXITOSAMENTE");
                 </script>';
}else{

    echo        '<script>
                        alert("La ambulancia fue actulizada EXITOSAMENTE");
                 </script>';

}
```

Comment: Hola, la información que brindas es muy poca, por lo que entiendo quieres actualizar el estado de una ambulancia, en tu consulta de actualización estas actualizando el estado de todas las ambulancias con estado `$estado`, lo correcto es que en el `where` coloques `id=$id`.

Comment: Quieres actualizar la tabla **ambulacia** verdad, imagino que su llave primaria es placa o cual es? a parte como se llama el campo que quieres actualizar y en que variable almacenas este nuevo valor?

Comment: actulizar el estado la llave es la placa

Comment: la llave es la placa y quiero actualizar el estado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en la Consulta hacia la Base de datos

**Tu codigo**

```
$query = "UPDATE SET ambulancia(estado) where estado = '".$estado."'";
```

**Solución**

```
$query = "UPDATE nombre_de_tabla SET columna=valor_formulario where columna_comparar= '".$valor_comparar."'";
```

**Ejemplo**

```
$query = "UPDATE ambulancia SET estado = 1 where id_usuario ='".$usuario."'";
```

Comment: no Funcionan los cambios muestra esto: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Administracion\modificarEstadoAmbu.php on line 5

Comment: El error aparte de la sentencia de base de datos puede ser la conexion, debes dar mas informacion

Comment: Correcto el primer error era la sentencia, ahora si tienes problemas de conexión a Base de datos o que falten campos en la tabla.. debes dar mas información

Comment: que informacion?

Comment: El error que te dio es que la variable $id no exitse, quiere decir que no lo pasas en el formulario...

Comment: en que parte no la estoy enviando la variable?